# matplotlib and backend 'agg' result in plot not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, backend

I'm trying to use matplotlib with Pycharm Community Ed. 2019.3, Python 3.7.3, Ubuntu 19.04.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(3,2,'.')
plt.show()
```

But get the following error code: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure."

I tried changing the backend to 'NbAgg':

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('NbAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(3,2,'.')
plt.show()
```

But get the following error code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leo/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 269, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 261, in show
    manager.show()
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 90, in show
    self._create_comm()
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 122, in _create_comm
    self.add_web_socket(comm)
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py", line 432, in add_web_socket
    self.resize(w, h)
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py", line 418, in resize
    size=(w / self.canvas._dpi_ratio, h / self.canvas._dpi_ratio))
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py", line 489, in _send_event
    s.send_json(payload)
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 199, in send_json
    self.comm.send({'data': json.dumps(content)})
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 123, in send
    data=data, metadata=metadata, buffers=buffers,
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 66, in _publish_msg
    self.kernel.session.send(self.kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 73, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 126, in destroy
    self._send_event('close')
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg_core.py", line 489, in _send_event
    s.send_json(payload)
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 199, in send_json
    self.comm.send({'data': json.dumps(content)})
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 123, in send
    data=data, metadata=metadata, buffers=buffers,
  File "/home/leo/PycharmProjects/Coursera/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 66, in _publish_msg
    self.kernel.session.send(self.kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
```

I understand that the backend and showing the plots are incompatible, but I don't understand what I need to do to match the backend and showing the plots.

Comment: `agg` is a non-interactive backend, it cannot show figures. `nbagg` is a backend used within IPython or notebooks, it cannot be used inside PyCharm. PyCharm has a custom backend, `interagg`, else you can use any of the [interactive backends](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) matplotlib supplies.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how can I utilize the custom backend interagg then?

Comment: I have no idea. It's a PyCharm thingy, and PyCharm is proprietary, so you need to look up in the manual or contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the backend to 'TkAgg', but I had to install tk via the command line using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

However, still need to use plt.show() for the graph to pop up

Comment: Yes, `plt.show()` is the command to show a figure in pyplot. So that's expected.